# get file name of selected file

Tags: javascript, dialog, electron

How can I get only the name of the selected Data. I do the following but get the whole path of the File. I would like to display the filename for the user

```
var dialog = require('electron').remote.dialog;

var url;

    document.getElementById('openButton').onclick = () => {

      dialog.showOpenDialog((fileName) => {
        if(fileName === undefined) {
          alert('No file selected');
        } else {
          console.log(fileName)

          url = fileName[0];
          console.log(url);
          $('#dataFileName').html(url)
        }
      })




    };
```

What i get is "/Users/void/Desktop/abc.xlsx" and I would like to have in addition to that only the file i opened.

Comment: isn't that the file you opened? Do you only want the name, not  the path?

Comment: plz edit to see what is the result of the `console.log(filename)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way you can grab just the file name:

```
var filePath = "/Users/void/Desktop/abc.xlsx";
var fileName = filePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

console.log(fileName);
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fb0mg2u6/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Awersomeness for regex demonstrated above

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [path.basename()](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext)

```
const {basename} = require('path')

let filePath = "/Users/void/Desktop/abc.xlsx"
let fileName = basename(filePath)
```

Comment: thats what i was actually looking for

Comment: Awesome for **Node.js**  `path` module

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can use this:

```
var mystring = "/Users/void/Desktop/abc.xlsx"; //replace your string 
var temp = mystring.split("/"); // split url into array
var fileName = temp[temp.length-1]; // get the last element of the array
```

What you basically do is to split your url with "/" regex, so you get each bit, and filename is always the last bit so you can get it with array's length you just created.

Comment: Have you considered other Operating Systems? The path style above and the slashes differ for different OSs.